# Warning: PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdoc

Tags: php

I am Getting Warning Like Warning: PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdoc And Values are not Going to insert in database.

Can anybody please me I am Stuck With Problem From Many Days

Here is code:-

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['btn_Add']))
    {     
      // Step 1: Establish a connection
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=DbName", 'root', '');
      $MaxId       ="2";
      $Feild_1 =$_POST['txt_Feild1'];        //datatype int
      $Feild_2       =$_POST['txt_Feild2'];  //datatype varchar
      $Feild_3        =$_POST['txt_Feild3']; //varchar  

      // Step 2: Construct a query  
      $insert_query=$conn->prepare("Insert INTO Dbname (Max_Id,     Feild_1, Feild_2, Feild_3) 
    values (:Max_Id,:Feild_1, :Feild_2, :Feild_3,");

    // Step 3: Send the query
    $result=$conn->query($insert_query);

    // STEP 4:Bind The Placeholder name to specific Script variables
   $insert_query->bindParam(':Max_Id',   $Max_Id); 
   $insert_query->bindParam(':Feild_1',   $Field_1);
   $insert_query->bindParam(':Feild_2',   $Field_1);
   $insert_query->bindParam(':Feild_3',   $Field_1); 

   //Step 5 Execute Query
   $insert_query->execute();

    }//OUTER IF END
   ?>
```

> PDO Warning :-Warning: PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\BSNL Project\Add_Pin_Unpin_File(Without Auto Increment).php on line 109

[[image]]

Comment: Try removing the `query($insert_query)` line. Calling query expects the SQL statement and executes immediately, which is not what you're expecting. As you use `execute` it isn't necessary.

Comment: Couple of other points, 1) as implied below, the SQL statement as provided is invalid. 2) Your code says insert into `Dbname` when you want to be interesting into a table?

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1 - Fix your SQL:

So, with the code you've given, you've actually got an SQL error. If we take the SQL out of the PHP, it looks like...

```
Insert INTO Dbname (Max_Id,     Feild_1, Feild_2, Feild_3) 
values (:Max_Id,:Feild_1, :Feild_2, :Feild_3,
```

So the issue with this is that, first, you have a trailing comma that shouldn't be there, and you're missing a trailing `)` that closes the values part of the query.

As a side note, you're using `Dbname` as a table name. Whether this is correct or not, we don't know, that depends on you.

#### Step 2 - Use PDO correctly:

The warning message you've provided is;

> PDO Warning :-Warning: PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\BSNL Project\Add_Pin_Unpin_File(Without Auto Increment).php on line 109

If you look at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) the `query` method expects at least one parameter which has to be a string. This method returns an instance of `PDOStatement` and runs an execute straight away. As far as I know, it does not support prepared statements.

So the warning comes because you've called `prepare` with your SQL statement which returns an object of type `PDOStatment`, and then pass that returned object as the first parameter which as expected throws a warning saying that you've not passed a string.

By simply removing the line `$result=$conn->query($insert_query);` you will remove the warning message without causing other issues as it's not necessary anyway as you bind and then execute the query manually afterwards.

If there are further issues, then I'd suggest you have a look at [setting the exception mode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) on your PDO connection variable and seeing what comes up.

#### Step 3 - Fix your binds

The final issue that I can see is with the following...

```
$insert_query->bindParam(':Max_Id',   $Max_Id);
```

You bind `$Max_Id` but earlier in your code, you actually create the variable `$MaxId`.

The same goes for the fields. You bind `$Field_1`, but your actual variable is `$Feild_1`.

Finally, you're binding the same variable for multiple placeholders which doesn't seem quite right when you appear to have defined different variables for each one.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call execute for the prepared queries.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

`$insert_query->execute();`

Comment: Thanks For Reply But Can Anybody tell that where i am getting Wrong in My Program

Comment: Actually In Post I Forget to Edit Code:-                                                          $insert_query->bindParam(':Feild_1',   $Field_1);
   $insert_query->bindParam(':Feild_2',   $Field_1);
   $insert_query->bindParam(':Feild_3',   $Field_1);                                                                                     Insted of Above Code It Should Be:-                                                                        $insert_query->bindParam(':Feild_1',   $Field_1);
   $insert_query->bindParam(':Feild_2',   $Field_2);
   $insert_query->bindParam(':Feild_3',   $Field_3);

Comment: Sorry I have Put My Mistake In Comment Due that i have Post the Question before 3 minutes.                                                                          Can't Re-post same  topic Post With Editing.